# Windows 10 Excel Worksheet .Range Issue

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that runs without any issues in Windows 7, but in Windows 10 it is erroring out at this line of code:

```
oWorksheet.Range("A1", "C1").Font.Bold = True
```

Error: HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

The thing is, I don't have a Windows 10 machine so I can't test it myself. Has anyone else seen this issue / have any ideas for a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: It'd really help if we know what error you were getting...

Comment: edited to include it, forgot about that

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/470089/Exception-from-HRESULT-x-A-EC-Error might help